# Cannot upload image chosen from gallery on Flutter: "Cannot extract a file path from a blob"

Tags: flutter

I have this image uploading API:
http://localhost:1234/simpleApi/image/upload

Given an image file **test_image.jpg**, here's how you upload it via [HTTPie](https://httpie.io/):

```
http POST http://localhost:1234/simpleApi/image/upload file@test_image.jpg
```

If uploaded succesfully, an UUID will be returned.

Now I'm trying to do the same thing on Flutter, first pick the image from gallery, then call the image upload API:

```
 pickImage() async {
    XFile? result;
    try {
      result = await ImagePicker().pickImage(
        source: ImageSource.gallery,
        imageQuality: 70,
        maxWidth: 1024,
      );
    } on PlatformException {
      Get.snackbar('', 'Cannot access gallery...');
    }

    if (result != null) {
      setState(() {
        _imgPath = result!.path;
      });
    }
  }
  
   uploadImage(String pathToFile) async {
   var IMAGE_UPLOAD_URL = 'http://localhost:1234/simpleApi/image/upload'
    
    var postUri = Uri.parse("IMAGE_UPLOAD_URL");
    var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", postUri);
    request.files.add(new http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('file', await File.fromUri(Uri.parse(pathToFile)).readAsBytes(), 
      contentType: new MediaType('image', 'jpeg')));

    request.send().then((response) {
      if (response.statusCode == 200) print("Upload OK");
      else ("Upload failed.");
    });
    
  }
```

After calling `pickImage`, it returns a value like this:

> blob:http://localhost:64692/a4b07098-0e83-46e2-8bdd-7a0a93aedec3

Passing that value to `uploadImage` gives this error:

> Error: Unsupported operation: Cannot extract a file path from a blob
> URI

How to fix this? I tested this on Flutter 2.2.3

Comment: You can first fix your `IMAGE_UPLOAD_URL` removing the **http POST** part

Comment: Aarrghh sorry. Fixed the `IMAGE_UPLOAD_URL`, and the same error still happens.

Answer (score 0):

You have everything right, the only thing you have to take note of is which platform are you reading this image from, when you check the example on Pub.dev you will notice that you have to check using kIsweb, that way the system will read your blob as a network image.

```
                      Obx(() => controller.filepath.value == ""
                              ? Text(
                                  "Select image",
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                                )
                              : Semantics(
                                  label:
                                      'image_picker_example_picked_image',
                                  **child: kIsWeb
                                      ? Image.network(
                                          controller.filepath.value)
                                      : Image.file(
                                          File(controller.filepath.value)),
                                )**
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of URI you can use this

```
http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
    'image',
    uint8list,
    filename: imageName,
);
```